# Smooth scroll to div element within div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, scrollto, smooth-scrolling, smoothing

I'm trying to work towards what I thought would be a fairly easy smooth scrollto effect, which resulted in a lot of frustration and confusion, that's why i came here for help (I'm sometimes not formulating things so well, so please correct me or tell me if something is unclear, thanks)

What I would like to achieve is:

A smooth scroll to div's that are inside of a div element.
And this times 2, so there will be 2 menu's and 2 div's containing div elements I want to scroll to.

I have tried numerous thing:

balupton.scrollto plugin: Does this but somehow it jumps back tot the top before it scrolls to the selected item.

flesler's jquery.scrollTo: Can not get it to work with divs inside a div.

And then jQuery Scrolltop: This somehow kept getting the coordinates of the div wrong

I made a quick jsfiddle with 1 menu and one div to give an idea: https://jsfiddle.net/6wmtfuuv/

html

```
<div id="nav">
 <a href="#pro1" id="project1"> button1 </a>  <br><br>
 <a href="#pro2" id="project2"> button2 </a>  <br><br>
 <a href="#pro3" id="project3"> button3 </a>  <br><br>
 <a href="#pro4" id="project4"> button4 </a>  <br><br>
 <a href="#pro5" id="project5"> button5 </a>  <br><br>
 <a href="#pro6" id="project6"> button6 </a>  <br><br>
</div>

<div id="wrapperleft">
 <div id="pro1">this is pro 1 </div>           
 <div id="pro2">this is pro 2 </div>           
 <div id="pro3">this is pro 3 </div>           
 <div id="pro4">this is pro 4 </div>           
 <div id="pro5">this is pro 5 </div>                            
 <div id="pro6">this is pro 6 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#wrapperleft {
 position:absolute;
 left:0px;
 top:0px;
 height:100%;
 overflow:scroll;
}

#pro1,#pro2,#pro3,#pro4,#pro5,#pro6 {
 position:relative;
 height:800px;
 width:300px;
}

#nav {
 position:fixed;
 z-index:200;
 top:20px;
 right:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have [this gist](https://gist.github.com/flesler/3f3e1166690108abf747) which shows all that's needed to achieve this.
I'll paste the contents here so there's no need to go inside.

```
<!-- Include jQuery from somewhere, must use version 1.8 or above -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("#target-element").offset().top
  }, 4000);
</script>
```

That should help you implement it.

Comment: Hi Ariel, Thanks for you answer, although somehow I dont get it to work, should I change anything in my current markup?

Comment: Hi, I slightly changed the code, I'm not sure if you changed your html on top or I got mine wrong, I changed the jQuery selector

Comment: Hi Ariel, for this tryout i didn't change the HTML, it is the same as the one above. Still dont get it to work. My HTML CSS and Jquery  are quite alright but my javascript is still very undeveloped, is there any clear tutorial somewhere that might be helpfull? Thanks in advance for the help, very much appreciated!